# Contact lookup via Email field

Tags: php, salesforce, php-toolkit

I am using *Force.com Toolkit for PHP (Version 20.0)* to integrate with Salesforce.

I would like to lookup some Contact via the email field and print in on page if the condition is met. Here is the query I used:

```
SELECT Name, Email, npe01__HomeEmail__c, npe01__WorkEmail__c, npe01__AlternateEmail__c FROM Contact WHERE Email = "a@a.com"
```

In [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) everything works fine, however, when I use the same query in PHP I get the following error:

> 'MALFORMED_QUERY: npe01__AlternateEmail__c FROM Contact WHERE Email="a@a.com"
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:112
>   Bind variables only allowed in Apex code'

What would be best practice to help me solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I know SOQL is weird with " have you tried just the query SELECT Name, Email, npe01__HomeEmail__c, npe01__WorkEmail__c, npe01__AlternateEmail__c FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'a@a.com' ?

Comment: Yes, the quotes don't matter. I even used a variable and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that [halfwarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370861/halfwarr) was right!
I used the following code to get this to work:

```
$donor_email = 'odedtalmon@gmail.com';
$query = 'SELECT Name, Email, npe01__HomeEmail__c, npe01__WorkEmail__c, npe01__AlternateEmail__c FROM Contact WHERE Email=\''.$donor_email.'\'';
```